# Google Ranking of Website through i-phone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to do an i-phone application which allows users to find the google ranking of website.Any one figured it before.?Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think google it self provides some service for this please see this 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Google_products#Mobile
it might be helpful.